# Expect `valid?` to return `false`, but always got `true`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I am studying Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial, and am stuck in validating. Here is my testing in console:

```
root@sample_app# rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0)
user = User.new(name: "", email: "mhartl@example.com")
#=> #<User id: nil, name: "", email: "mhartl@example.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
user.valid?
#=> true

user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "mhartl@example.com")
#=> #<User id: nil, name: "Example User", email: "mhartl@example.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
user.valid?
#=> true
```

No matter what the name is, `user.valid?` always returns `true`. Anybody know why?

Comment: Can you provide your validations for the `name` field?

Answer (score 4):

Unless you tell it that there needs to be some validations applied, it will assume that having an empty name is OK.

An example of a validation for this example would be:

```
validates :name, presence: true, allow_blank: false
```

You can read about validations [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

Comment: Adding `, allow_blank: false` to that validation should get the behaviour David's after.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Base on your hint, I found the reason: In rails console, I need write the validation. So,

Answer (score 0):

The reason is: in rails console, I need type the validation.

```
root@sample_app# rails console --sandbox
Loading development environment in sandbox (Rails 4.2.0)
Any modifications you make will be rolled back on exit

>> class User < ActiveRecord::Base
>>   validates(:name, presence: true)
>> end
=> {:presence=>true}
>> user = User.new(name: "", email: "mhartl@example.com")
=> #<User id: nil, name: "", email: "mhartl@example.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> user.valid?
=> false

>> user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "mhartl@example.com")
=> #<User id: nil, name: "Example User", email: "mhartl@example.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> user.valid?
=> true
>>
```